# Calling objects within this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array and there are objects within it. However when I print
`console.log(Objex)`  it will print the array but calling
`console.log(Objex.Pri)` gives me undefined.

[The console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwX5.png)

```
            var finalData= []

            Objex.push({
            "Pri":  result[i],
            "Sec":  {
              secTask: res1,
              childTask:res2
            }

            console.log(Objex[0].Pri)
```

The whole code is shown below

```
               fetch("http://localhost:3001/primain")
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((result) => {
  //    this.setState({ priResponse: result })
    for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
      fetch(`http://localhost:3001/second/${result[i].PrimaryID}`)
        .then((res1) => res1.json())
        .then((res1) => {
          for(let j=0;j<res1.length;j++){
            fetch(`http://localhost:3001/second/${res1[j].PrimaryID}`)
              .then((res2) => res2.json())
              .then((res2) => {
          finalData.push({
            "Pri":  result[i],
            "Sec":  {
              secTask: res1,
              childTask:res2
            }
          })
          console.log(finalData[i]) // this line prints properly 
          });
        }
        });
    }
      this.setState({ finalResponse: finalData});
      console.log(finalData[0].Pri) // this line doesnt
     }
```

Comment: Individual array members are referenced by index number in square brackets. e.g. `Objex[0].Pri`

Comment: To print all you can do `Objex.forEach(o=>console.log(o.Pri))` To print the first one you can do `console.log(Objex[0].Pri)`

Comment: What was your expected result? Did you want a new array of all the values of `.Pri` for each object? Something else?

Comment: that doesn't work as well gives me  TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pri' of undefined

Comment: Yes have tried Objex.Pri , Objex[0].Pri, Objex["0"].Pri

Comment: No code AND `doesn't work`, please update your question.

Comment: Noted will update

Comment: @HMR the code has been updated

Comment: Well you don't define Objex anywhere.

Comment: Oh.  It's because you expect what happens inside a `.then` to be available before the async operation even starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous, you can't just mutate an array inside a promise and expect it do be set after the promise. You should set state inside the promise:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/primain')
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result =>
    Promise.all(
      result.map(result =>
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:3001/second/${result.PrimaryID}`
        )
          .then(res1 => res1.json())
          .then(res1 =>
            Promise.all(
              res1.map(res1 =>
                fetch(
                  `http://localhost:3001/second/${res1.PrimaryID}`
                ).then(res2 => res2.json())
              )
            )
          )
      )
    )
  )
  .then(finalResult => {
    console.log(finalResult);
    //do a this.setState here
  });
```

When you log an expandable object and expand that object you'll see the object as it is now and not as it was when you logged it. You can JSON.stringify an object to see the value of the object at the time of logging. Try the following code in the console.

```
const s = [{name:'original'}];
console.log('logs as is when you expand',s);
console.log('logs as was at the log time',JSON.stringify(s,undefined,2));
s[0].name='changed it';
```

Comment: I tried this as well but now I am not getting the correct data as the final array only consist of the res2 . res1 and result are not present within the array

Comment: It works, I added a push command where the res2 promise finishes and it finally worked. Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to call the first element of your array before you can call `.Pri`.

Try this:

```
console.log(Objex[0].Pri);
```